# Fragment onBackPressed method called by other Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a little problem with ViewPager and Fragment implementation.

I have 4 Fragments {A;B;C:D} in a ViewPager, one of those is a profile view (D fragments). When user logs in, i have a FragmentTransaction that replace that profile view with a detail profile view {D --- D1}. In that detail profile view view i've implemented a custom onBackPressed behavior, only for that fragment like this

```
    this.rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.rootView.requestFocus();
    this.rootView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                final MaterialDialog mMaterialDialog = new 
                MaterialDialog(getActivity());
                mMaterialDialog.setTitle("LOG OUT")
                        .setMessage("If you log out right now, you will not be able to make a booking")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                                user.logOut();

                                mMaterialDialog.dismiss();

                                FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager()
                                        .beginTransaction();
                                trans.replace(R.id.profile_frame, new ProfileFragment());
                                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                                trans.commit();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mMaterialDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                mMaterialDialog.show();


                return true;
            }

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
                    break;

            }

            return true;

        }
    });
```

**My problem is when user clicks back button for example in fragment B, it triggers fragment D1 method. Why is that happening?. Here is my main activity and complete fragment D1 code**

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout; private LinearLayout settings, booking, about;
private Button contactUs, visitOurSite;
private DrawerLayout drawer; private LinearLayout drawerContent;
private Tracker tracker;
private Fragment musicFrag, profileDetailFrag, filterFrag, mapFrag, profileFrag, favoritesFrag;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIconsUnselected = {
        R.drawable.tab_home,
        R.drawable.tab_map,
        R.drawable.tab_favorites,
        R.drawable.tab_profile
};

private int[] tabIconsSelected = {
        R.drawable.tab_home_pressed,
        R.drawable.tab_map_pressed,
        R.drawable.tab_favorites_pressed,
        R.drawable.tab_profile_pressed
};

public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private Window window;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Typeface semiBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GillSans-SemiBold.ttf");
    Typeface light = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GillSans-Light.ttf");
    Typeface bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GillSans-Bold.ttf");

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ParallaxPagerTransformer(R.id.parallax_content));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory("Tabs").setAction("Click").setLabel("Home tab").build());
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    setPressed(tab.getPosition());

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        window = getWindow();
                        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSecondaryDark));
                    }

                    break;
                case 1:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    setPressed(tab.getPosition());

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        window = getWindow();
                        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSecondaryDark));
                    }

                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    setPressed(tab.getPosition());

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        window = getWindow();
                        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSecondaryDark));
                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    setPressed(tab.getPosition());

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        window = getWindow();
                        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    contactUs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact);
    contactUs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory("Navigation Drawer").setAction("Click").setLabel("Contact Us").build());
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactUsActivity.class));
        }
    });

    visitOurSite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.web);
    visitOurSite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://landing.vamospues.co");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    settings = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
    TextView settingsLabel = (TextView) settings.getChildAt(1);
    settingsLabel.setTypeface(semiBold);

    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    booking = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.booking_button);
    booking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookingActivity.class));
        }
    });
    TextView reservationsLabel = (TextView) booking.getChildAt(1);
    reservationsLabel.setTypeface(semiBold);

    about = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    TextView aboutLabel = (TextView) about.getChildAt(1);
    aboutLabel.setTypeface(semiBold);

    about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory("Navigation Drawer").setAction("Click").setLabel("About").build());
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class));
        }
    });

    setupTabIcons();
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawer.openDrawer(findViewById(R.id.drawer_content));
}

private void setPressed(int i) {
    if (i==0){
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIconsSelected[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[3]);
    }
    if (i==1){
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIconsSelected[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[3]);
    }
    if (i==2){
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIconsSelected[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[3]);
    }
    if (i==3){
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIconsSelected[3]);
    }
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIconsSelected[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIconsUnselected[3]);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new FilterFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFrag(new MapFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFrag(new FavoritesFragment(), "THREE");
    adapter.addFrag(new ProfileFragment(), "FOUR");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

**FRAGMENT D1**

```
   public class ProfileDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private View rootView; RotateLoading loader;
private CircleImageView profilePic; ScrollView profileContainer;
private String id, name, mail, birthday, phone, url;
private TextView nameLabel, mailLabel, birthdayLabel, phoneLabel;
private Bitmap picture;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (rootView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_detail_fragment, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {

    }

    if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == null){
        FragmentTransaction trans = getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(R.id.profile_frame, new ProfileFragment());
        trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        trans.commit();
    }

    loader = (RotateLoading) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading);
    profileContainer = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_container);
    profileContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    nameLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    mailLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mail_label);
    birthdayLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.birthday_label);
    phoneLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phone_label);
    profilePic = (CircleImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

    this.rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.rootView.requestFocus();
    this.rootView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                final MaterialDialog mMaterialDialog = new MaterialDialog(getActivity());
                mMaterialDialog.setTitle("LOG OUT")
                        .setMessage("If you log out right now, you will not be able to make a booking")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                                user.logOut();

                                mMaterialDialog.dismiss();

                                FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager()
                                        .beginTransaction();
                                trans.replace(R.id.profile_frame, new ProfileFragment());
                                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                                trans.commit();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mMaterialDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                mMaterialDialog.show();


                return true;
            }

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
                    break;

            }

            return true;

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

public class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loader.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        id = user.get("id").toString();
        name = user.get("name").toString();
        mail = user.getEmail();
        birthday = user.get("birthday").toString();
        phone = user.get("phone").toString();
        url = user.get("pic_url").toString();

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        loader.stop();
        profileContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(profilePic);
        birthdayLabel.setText(birthday);
        mailLabel.setText(mail);
        nameLabel.setText(name);
        phoneLabel.setText(phone);

    }
}
```

}

**THANKS FOR YOUR HELP :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very strangely architected project you're creating. In any case you're not actually handling on back pressed events, you're handling any type of keypress in D1. That is a problem but the other problem is that all of your fragments exist at the same time, even though you can only see the one. What you need to do is correctly handle `onBackPressed()` (The method exists on the activity, not on the Fragment)

To handle it, you need to keep track of what Fragment is currently displayed and check whether to pass the event to the Fragment. Because onBackPressed doesn't follow the usual event signature we can't simply return false to say don't let the event propagate, so instead you need to remove the listener from your D Fragment (which im going to assume for now is ProfileFragment), and put the code into your own method (Lets assume you call that onBackPressed too)

On the activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //NOTE: I havent checked if getSelectedPosition exists, so track it however you want
    if ( viewPager.getSelectedPosition() == 3 ) {
        ((ProfileFragment) profileFragment).onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed(); 
    }
}
```

then on ProfileFragment / D

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    final MaterialDialog mMaterialDialog = new MaterialDialog(getActivity());
    ...
    mMaterialDialog.show();
}
```